# Properly using "interfaces" in C++?

Tags: c++, interface, coding-style

I haven't done hard core development in C++ since I made the switch to C# about 5 years ago.  I'm very familiar with using interfaces in C# and use them all the time.  For example

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
   string SomeString { get; set; }
}

public class MyClass : IMyInterface
{
   public string SomeString { get; set; }
}

// This procedure is designed to operate off an interface, not a class.
void SomeProcedure(IMyInterface Param)
{
}
```

This is all great since you can implement lots of similar classes and pass them around, and no one is the wiser that you are actually using different classes.  However, in C++ you can't pass the interface around because you'll get a compile error when it sees you trying to instantiate a class that does not have all its methods defined.

```
class IMyInterface
{
public:
   ...
   // This pure virtual function makes this class abstract.
   virtual void IMyInterface::PureVirtualFunction() = 0;
   ... 
}



class MyClass : public IMyInterface
{
public:
   ...
   void IMyInterface::PureVirtualFunction();
   ... 
}


// The problem with this is that you can't declare a function like this in
// C++ since IMyInterface is not instantiateable.
void SomeProcedure(IMyInterface Param)
{
}
```

**So what is the proper way to get the feel of C# style interfaces in C++?**

Comment: Don't forget to add virtual destructor for your `IMyInterface` class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure you can, but you need to pass references or pointers, not by value (well, pedantically speaking, pointers are passed by value as well):

```
void SomeProcedure(IMyInterface& Param)
```

I think it's similar to C# in that regard, only that C# passes references to classes by default, whereas in C++ you explicitly have to say you want to pass it by reference.

The pass by value will attempt to create a copy of the object, and an object of an abstract type (interface) doesn't make sense, ergo the error.

Comment: It feels a little strange using a pointer like this.  I was thinking there was just some syntax I didn't know about that would get me what I wanted.  But yes, using a pointer to my "interface" works just fine.  Thanks :D

Answer (score 3):

> However, in C++ you can't pass the interface around...

You can pass a *pointer* or a *reference* to an abstract class, e.g.:

```
void SomeProcedure(IMyInterface& Param) { ... }
```

or

```
void SomeProcedure(const IMyInterface& Param) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you can't pass an abstract (interface class) to a function is that the size of the object needs to be know when the copy is made.

This obviously wouldn't make a difference if all your classes are the same size, but the compiler often can't know what your intentions are, and it's very common that the implementation actually has member variables that aren't present in the base/interface class [in fact, a clean implementation shouldn't contain any data at all].

To avoid having to know the size, we pass a pointer to, or a reference. Now the compiler only needs to know the size of the pointer - which is something the compiler can know at any time.

So as other answers say, you pass a reference, const references, or pointer to the interface, and the implementation object can be passed in without needing to know exactly which one it is.

Similarly, if you want to store some implementations of the same base-class, you store references or pointers to the base, and then let those refer/point to the actual object that of an implementation class.

Answer (score 0):

The current code in the question:

```
class IMyInterface
{
public:
   ...
   // This pure virtual function makes this class abstract.
   virtual void IMyInterface::PureVirtualFunction() = 1;
   ... 
}
```

There's just **too much wrong** with this.

- The `IMyInterface::` is a language extension, if it compiles with any compiler (similar stuff used to compile with Visual C++).
- The `= 1` is a syntax error. Probably the author means `= 0`.
- The `}` without a semicolon will cause a later parsing error.

Diagnosing a particular thing in the later code as cause of the OP's problem, as the existing answers so far do, is therefore pure guesswork. Plausible, yes. But hey, when the OP writes that the problem is

> “because you'll get a compile error”

he or she is *already getting that* with the above fantasy code.

Continuing the question's code:

```
class MyClass : public IMyInterface
{
public:
   ...
   void IMyInterface::PureVirtualFunction();
   ... 
}

// The problem with this is that you can't declare a function like this in
// C++ since IMyInterface is not instantiateable.
void SomeProcedure(IMyInterface Param)
{
}
```

Applying the super-long-distance iterative convergent telepathic circuit, I'm guessing code like the following could have been meant:

```
class IMyInterface
{
public:
   // ...
   virtual void pureVirtualFunction() = 0;
};

class MyClass
    : public virtual IMyInterface
{
public:
   // ...
   void PureVirtualFunction();
};

void SomeProcedure( IMyInterface const& param )
{
}
```

Then, having corrected the myriad syntax errors etc., just so that the code *compiles*, there's no apparent problem left to deal with: no question.

Disclaimer: untouched by compiler's hands. Also, since no question, no discussion. I merely offer that programming requires intelligence, it can't be reduced to rules suitable for machines, hence do not take the above as absolute rules to follow.